# SQL-Server and Parallel.ForEach Table Creation

Tags: c#, sql-server, task-parallel-library, create-table, parallel.foreach

I am experimenting with Parallel.ForEach in C# and SQL-Server Database Connectivity and table creation. By and large, trying to create a large number of tables using Parallel.ForEach. Although the code is running, I notice data leakage as not all tables are created. I am reading data from Microsoft.Data.Analysis DataFrame which is IEnumerable. Therefore, I would like to ask just for a skeleton of how can I run Parallel.ForEach with SQL connectivity and Commands in order to have multiple different table creation running on parallel threads on the same database and creating at the same time multiple tables, but to make sure all tables are created. I am not an experienced user of C#, so thank you in advance for your help....

Here is some code also, sorry for bad formatting (first time...)

```
Task task_111 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{    
   Parallel.ForEach<string>(list, iter =>
   { 
       using (var myConn=new SqlConnection())
       DataFrame LoadExample = DataFrame.LoadCsv();
       {
         // ......
         {
           string sql= // create table
           {
              using (var command=new SqlCommand())
              { 
                command_2.Connection = myConn;
                command_2.CommandText = sql;
                myConn.Open();
                command_2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myConn.Close();
              }
             .......
```

Comment: It's helpful to show your actual code so we can see if you are doing anything wrong.

Comment: You only need proper exception handling.  IE don't catch and "eat" exceptions, and see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-handle-exceptions-in-parallel-loops

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Can I use Microsoft.Data.Analysis DataFrame class with Parallel.ForEach? Now I will also attach some code..... Thanks Lolop... Sorry for bad formatting, I will try to be better in each iteration.

Comment: Get rid of the outer task and just run Parallel.Foreach.  You should get an Exception if there are any errors.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft at the time the comment was posted, there was no code in the question

Comment: Are you awaiting the `task_111` task somewhere, or you are letting it run in a fire-and-forget fashion? You should `await` your tasks, so that you are notified about their completion, and so that you can observe and log any exceptions that may have occurred.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, there were some exceptions... Thanks a lot...